# How to send complex JSON structure from angular to spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring

I've a JSON like below in my angular controller, which i need to post to Spring controller.

```
var items={"A":"aa",
           "B":"bb",
           "C":{"D":"dd", "E":"ee"}
           };

$http.post('localhost:8082/ProjectName/posting',items)
.success(function(data,status,headers, config){
   alert("success");
})
.error(function(error){
    alert(error);
});
```

In my Spring controller

```
@RestController
public class ForPost{
  @RequestMapping(value="/posting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody List  forPosting(@RequestBody PostingModel postingModel){
    System.out.println("Print all values received");
    .
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

*I'm thinking for this kind of nested JSON, I need to have nested POJO.
something like:*

```
public class PostingModel{
 String A;
 String B;
 POJOForC C;
 /* getter setter below*/
}

puublic class POJOForC{
 String D;
 String E;
 /* getter setter below*/
}
```

I get error message: **The request sent by client was syntactically incorrect().**
Am I accepting the values correctly? Need to fix something in POJO?

Comment: Have you tried to send the request from rest clients e.g postman?

Comment: Did you try with exact example you have posted?

Comment: @Nayan no. I've not used any rest clients

Comment: @sura2k yes, exact same example.

Comment: Is my pojo class correct?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to serialize the json as below:

```
$http.post('localhost:8082/ProjectName/posting',JSON.Stringify(items))
.success(function(data,status,headers, config){
   alert("success");
})
.error(function(error){
    alert(error);
});
```

Then the Model receives the json as :

```
public class PostingModel { 
   String reqJson;
 }

@RestController
public class ForPost{
  @RequestMapping(value="/posting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody List  forPosting(@RequestBody PostingModel postingModel){

    //You would need to parse the json here to retrieve the objects
    //Use GSON or Jackson to parse the recieved json.
      JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(postingModel.reqJson);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this work for complex JSONs? Like the one i mentioned in my question?

Comment: Definitely it would. you get the complete json here, you could break it into individual string and objects using the models you made.

Comment: I just now tested.. it works only when I don't have a nested JSON like the one in example.